# Is there a way to customise the product dimension subfields in Expresso?

Tags: expresso-store

By default products have subfields for width, height, length etc. Is there a way to change these on the admin side? I'd like to change length to 'overall width' and weight to 'overall height'. Any clues would be great.

Answer (score 1):

No.

But, try using this [add-on](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cp-css-js) to inject custom JS into the control panel then modify the labels via JS. Something like...

```
// Publish/Edit Entry
$('#publish #store_product_field thead th:eq(2)').text("Overall Width (mm)");
$('#publish #store_product_field thead th:eq(5)').text("Overall Height (mm)");
```

Do something similar for the Store Control Panel page(s). On the frontend you control the labelling anyway.

The alternative is just to create custom fields in your entry to handle the information.